# What does the Clone Wars animated series add to the recent Star Wars Trillogy?

Tags: star-wars, canon, the-clone-wars

I've just seen a completely [epic trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlJcpymtAco) for some of the Clone Wars animated series. It looks like it fills in

> how Darth Maul came back to try and take revenge on Obi-wan

I know this story from research, but it piqued my interest as I had assumed that the show was mostly filler and didn't contribute a significant amount to the Expanded Universe for Star Wars, not did I think it related much to star wars canon of any level. *Is that so?*

As well as this, the publication of this raises Maul's story from C-Canon to T-canon. Is there new content from this show that effects the Canonicity of other aspects of the EU?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Roughly, it adds these things:

1. A more fleshed-out arc for Anakin's transition from Jedi to Sith.
2. Additional attention to various niches within *Star Wars* canon that the films could never spend time on.  The Witches of Dathomir arc is an example of this.  As you mention, this show's work in this area also provides T-canon, instead of the books' C (or S)-canon.
3. A thorough view on the events of the *Clone Wars*.  This is an epic conflict that reshaped the galactic civilization.  Having more than ~6 hours to devote to it enables deeper storytelling.
4. You get to see Jedi in action on a weekly basis.  Who doesn't love seeing lightsabers in action?

Comment: To #4, the dismemberment ward at the hospital is probably tired of it by now.

Comment: To #4, presumably, the Sith :)

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen the volume 1 disk, but the last parts of the volume 2 disk leads directly into the opening events of Revenge of the Sith, showing the assault on Coruscant and the kidnapping of Palpatine.

Comment: I think you're referring to [Star Wars: Clone Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Clone_Wars_%282003_TV_series%29), but the question is asking about [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_%282008_TV_series%29).  And yes, the titles *are* confusing.